# Graph with lognormal probability fit and probability occurance

Tags: python

I recently started using python for my data analysis and have this problem given below.
I have a set of length measurements (pasted below). I made a lognormal fit to the lengths.

My script:

```
data=np.array(R0)
sig,loc, mu=lognorm.fit(data, loc=0)
print(sig, loc, mu)
est_mu=np.log(mu)
mean=np.exp(est_mu + ((sig**2)/2))
print(mean)
plt.hist(data, bins=200, normed=True, color='c', alpha=0.75)
xmin = data.min()
xmax = data.max()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 1000)
pdf = lognorm.pdf(x, sig, scale=mu)
plt.plot(x, pdf, 'k', lw=2)
plt.xlim(xmax=100)
plt.show()
```

17.648,   27.666,   11.016,    9.779,    9.176,   21.496,
         45.725,    6.077,    9.534,   25.074,    8.225,    7.651,
         17.229,   11.251,    3.598,    5.252,   14.622,    7.012,
          3.958,   11.022,   23.165,    8.561,    7.132,    4.677,
         10.143,   21.844,   10.613,   17.426,   19.967,   16.152,
         25.279,   11.379,    6.137,    3.982,    4.015,    6.116,
          5.794,    8.593,   13.006,    5.003,    6.953,    5.495,
          9.706,   10.538,   24.762,    4.656,   37.064,   12.382,
         16.636,    6.002,    9.035,   15.035,    9.986,   12.981,
          6.383,    5.906,   15.096,    8.547,    8.157,   11.339,
         15.183,   12.595,    5.093,   91.611,    6.343,    3.586,
          6.117,    3.598,    4.408,   37.298,    3.67 ,   23.891,
          7.809,    7.409,   17.367,   12.122,   10.231,    8.354,
         10.007,   27.254,   26.09 ,    6.474,    4.559,   10.672,
          5.738,    2.648,    8.884,   10.861,    2.159,   10.515,
          6.068,    7.654,   12.195,    7.41 ,    5.774,    7.099,
          8.744,    6.014,    5.934,    9.664,    5.296,    2.15 ,
          5.544,   29.579,    1.979,   24.426,    8.455,   10.924,
         15.311,    4.522,    5.297,    8.996,   15.947,   10.793,
         13.507,   16.749,   18.107,    3.362,   14.476,    7.52 ,
          5.756,    4.873,   12.076,   18.12 ,    5.756,    2.742,
          5.397,   25.848,   15.033,    4.643,    6.391,   13.241,
         11.219,   11.124,   10.741,   11.695,    5.507,   16.328,
          8.763,    8.107,   45.584,   21.057,   10.155,    5.24 ,
          5.178,    2.367,    8.164,   14.347,   15.214,    8.474,
         11.953,    5.845,    3.692,   18.576,    8.705,   11.649,
         24.352,   20.386,    9.556,    7.973,    8.789,   26.524,
          3.634,    9.701,   13.098,    6.448,   10.177,   24.611,
         10.61 ,   17.789,    3.418,    9.355,    5.672,    7.555,
         13.411,    5.691,    3.983,    6.183,   22.338,   12.958,
         12.465,    7.656,    5.461,    5.936,   10.017,    7.228,
          4.857,   15.089,   13.351,    9.663,   18.683,    4.137,
          7.508,   12.724,    7.287,    5.868,    5.205,    4.285,
          5.037,   11.254,    5.749,    9.124,    5.183,   36.628,
        221.36 ,    8.547,    9.372,    8.17 ,    4.937,    7.807,
         11.203,   10.184,   16.937,   21.989,   41.24 ,    7.751,
          5.155,    7.208,   16.618,    9.411,    3.475,    2.698,
         18.455,   47.067,    8.452,    6.896,    6.287,   12.938,
         10.939,    8.814,   11.89 ,    7.685,   34.591,    7.437,
         12.402,    9.728,   17.018,   16.65 ,   12.904,    7.016,
         13.25 ,   16.881,   14.099,   10.304,   27.82 ,    8.308,
         10.11 ,    7.249,    8.615,   10.522,    9.509,    5.775,
          6.38 ,    6.134,    7.251,   10.635,   11.029,    8.844,
          6.585,   15.063,    6.129,    7.213,    6.864,   10.368,
          5.378,   11.752,    3.746,    8.389,    4.839,    7.847,
         24.221,   13.046,   15.547,    5.44 ,    8.501,    5.593,
         58.495,   12.027,    9.096,    5.685,   12.169,    9.746,
         11.714,    6.655,    7.936,   40.984,   20.386,    7.965,
         11.565,   15.374,    8.882,    4.181,   25.022,    7.44 ,
         17.461,   11.128,   11.602,   26.285,   14.571,    9.51 ,
          9.163,    7.226,    7.37 ,   13.927,    6.928,    6.619,
         27.418,    7.555,    6.282,   21.891,   32.833,   12.918,
          7.687,    9.842,   18.294,   11.22 ,    6.377,    9.299,
         11.736,   22.436,   34.386,   10.874,    5.463,   12.046,
         13.23 ,   10.714,   22.224,   17.372,    5.596,   31.297,
         14.381,   16.848,    9.195,    6.425,   27.292,   12.945,
         34.391,   10.665,    8.995,    7.249,    8.424,   15.385,
         53.774,   23.743,    4.521,    9.714,   12.7  ,   33.629,
         14.605,   25.513,   24.347,   27.3  ,   32.531,    9.538,
         39.054,   21.92 ,   11.28 ,   22.648,   20.664,   22.578,
          8.022,    6.98 ,   16.549,    4.752,   16.507,   25.815,
         25.66 ,   36.848,   17.803,   13.76 ,   13.36 ,    8.994,
         23.603,    9.001,   26.949,   10.714,   10.796,   30.991,
         34.404,   11.877,   14.423,   38.302,   41.899,   23.424,
          9.967,   11.532,   19.422,   21.605,    5.905,   44.344,
         12.717,    5.549,   11.777,   12.309,   22.736,   11.693,
          9.014,    4.276,   14.747,   16.941,    9.714,   17.851,
         17.207,    9.004,   39.633,   19.456,   15.684,   17.25 ,
         22.088,   20.25 ,   15.725,   15.793,   16.781,   13.373,
         13.547,    7.677,   24.117,   10.392,   24.756,   15.258,
         12.546,   72.518,   35.263,    5.037,   13.28 ,   14.758,
         58.34 ,   10.357,   45.442,   26.091,   23.219,   30.244,
         10.34 ,   29.596,   19.727,   14.878,   31.585,   11.789,
          6.994,   11.708,   16.175,   10.863,   11.122,   25.317,
          7.061,   26.499,    6.676,   21.077,    8.132,    7.835,
          7.927,   19.991,   36.253,   12.539,   11.132,   30.553,
         14.955,   22.234,    9.776,   27.305,   30.167,   11.229,
         12.811,   29.938,   10.833,   28.724,   24.441,   14.562,
         26.585,   11.074,   12.13 ,    8.634,   25.328,   14.803,
         12.678,   26.18 ,   10.916,   18.151,   28.292,    9.193,
         11.639,   16.1  ,   15.228,   12.954,   14.962,   21.931,
         27.64 ,   13.111,   46.19 ,    6.383,    7.754,   10.   ,
          7.424,   12.329,    9.27 ,   50.592,   29.975,   14.855,
         17.547,   14.061,   12.422,   17.874,   22.45 ,   15.389,
         15.805,   30.501,   10.006,   31.134,   10.875,   17.682,
         18.235,    8.77 ,    8.25 ,   13.128,   16.129,   35.083,
         17.071,   23.537,   14.711,   17.319,   12.652,    7.955,
          8.306,   23.165,   18.063,   17.382,   14.403,   11.982,
         15.31 ,    9.677,   13.226,    7.215,   54.364,    9.478,
         14.531,    9.991,   40.147,   13.544,   14.622,   12.526,
          7.764,   11.384,   15.853,   40.147,   13.544,   14.622,
         12.526,    7.764,   11.384,   33.182,    7.02 ,   11.844,
         12.809,   26.306,   10.973,   19.911,    7.42 ,   11.361,
          8.275,   37.98 ,    6.114,   20.564,   12.127,    6.207,
         14.248,   15.079,   11.612,   27.904,   25.981,   11.421,
          8.361,   18.337,   23.063,   10.429,   52.738,   38.2  ,
         12.305,   16.613,   20.698,   16.748,   20.742,   13.239,
          7.735,    5.009,   31.637,   22.905,    7.092,   16.358,
         18.542,   28.253,   11.301,    5.539,   38.457,   28.746,
         15.219,    8.933,    7.782,    8.007,   11.688,    8.751,
         29.256,   11.461,    8.331,    6.847,   38.053,    7.56 ,
         16.814,    5.292,   33.663,   18.722,    7.684,   39.451,
          7.711,    9.792,   18.945,   17.884,   21.036,   22.555,
         19.134,   23.884,   13.77 ,    7.064,   59.767,   48.924,
         14.243,   11.992,   23.318,   25.61 ,   15.559,   42.494,
         79.566,   19.149,   18.311,   10.973,    6.656,   11.115,
         29.099,    9.043,    4.241,   11.848,   10.527,   16.133,
         19.106,   22.817,   12.659,    8.985,    8.553,   13.679,
          9.199,   17.466,    9.938,    9.342,   10.093,    8.204,
          8.306,    6.296,    9.587,   24.373,   27.332,   14.177,
         11.264,    6.475,   10.362,   17.01 ,   37.356,   12.779,
         26.419,   16.382,   16.908,   18.031,   23.627,   29.821,
         15.553,   18.98 ,   19.46 ,   40.692,   12.296,    8.709,
         13.124,    7.722,    3.074,    5.217,   14.904,   14.301,
         20.765,    9.689,   15.225,   10.912,   15.686,   11.919,
         10.714,   16.777,    8.712,   17.716,    8.994,    7.555,
         23.07 ,   24.158,   10.296,   16.22 ,    5.389,    9.916,
          5.966,   13.682,   13.946,    7.759,   25.723,    8.656,
         14.763,   22.582,   12.798,   17.976,   15.203

I, now, want to plot a figure with the length measurements on the X-axis and the probability of occurrence of those lengths on the Y-axis. I could not find anything similar here.

Can someone please point the direction to proceed further?

Comment: It sounds like you want to draw the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function for these data. Yes?

Comment: Yes, something similar. Not with a step function. The data should be roughly in a straight line as it is lognormal fitted. Can you suggest me something?

Comment: Another possibility: You have estimated parameters for the log-normal. This implies that you can define the distribution function for that log-normal. Therefore, you can apply the probability integral transform (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform) to these data so that they have a uniform distribution. If you plot the empirical distribution function for the transformed data it will be a (nearly) straight line.